# Obliterate the URL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an AJAX application that will call a servlet to run the report and return a PDF. This all works pretty well, except that the user will then be presented with a web page that will have the report name and their customer ID. Changing the customer ID will allow them to run the same report for another person. Yikes!

I recall some things about URL re-writing, which was used dubiously for session management. I was wondering if I could just modify the URL inside my servlet so that what the user gets back can't be hacked at to get other reports. How would I go about this?

Also, does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks.

Comment: If the data is reserved, you should make the users log in before they can see it...

Comment: How are you authenticating/authorizing requests generally?

Comment: Users must be authenticated before they can run the report. But I can't prevent the authenticated user from seeing other reports. So this problem has nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: This is an issue of authorization.  Authorization is not just about locking down certain pages based on user role -- it's common to need to authorize a user to view a certain resource based on their own relationship to that resource.  You should only be able to see your own shopping cart, for example. So, when you test whether the user is authorized to see a report, that test should include checking that the customer ID belongs to the logged in user (or that the user is an admin, who presumably is allowed to see other peoples' reports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a proxy servlet to copy the content across. This is triggered by a hash key that stores the URL parameters in the session. This gives me all the security I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the (anonymous) session ID as file part. And let a servlet stream the file in the file system by adding the session ID.

This assumes the control flow can't be done easier because of Ajax and doing two things at once.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as GarethL already stated in his comment, the users should have to log in. You could then store the customer id in the session and use this instead of a parameter.

The problem is that you first need to confirm the identity of the user somehow, the simplest way being a password.